# On scroll, show after x pixels, and remove after x pixels?

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery(function($){
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y > 500) {
    $('.popupcorner-desktop').fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('.popupcorner-desktop').fadeOut();
  }
});
});
```

This fades in on 500 and fades out if it is less.
What about if I want it to show between 500 and 1500 only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `&&` inside your `if()` to match two conditions simultaneously: `y > 500` and `y < 1500` like this:

```
if (y > 500 && y < 1500) {
  ...
}
```

or shorter

```
if (500 < y < 1500) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: It is correct answer indeed, but somewhy I cannot get it working, iut display imidiately and never goes of screen. Scrolling has no effect.

Comment: @mariobalser Check if your `.popupcorner-desktop` object exists at all. Also you can use `var y = document.documentElement.scrollTop;` instead of `var y = $(this).scrollTop();`

Comment: @mariobalser the "short version" I suggested isn't working... strange. But `if (y > 500 && y < 1500) {` works just fine in the fiddle.